# Shopp plugin for wordpress - Digital products with multiple files

Tags: wordpress, shopp

Trying to figure out if there is an extension out there that will allow the option of multiple files for a digital plugin in **Shopp plugin** for **wordpress**.

We have a catalogue of mp3s (podcast episodes) that we want to sell by season, we also want to sell these seasons in a "mega pack" which is cheaper if you buy them all. We were going to upload one single zip file with all the seasons in it but this would be approx 30gb.

Currently, the Add ons functionality in Shopp is pretty close to what we want but it requires the user to select the options rather than just having them on by default.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a function to your theme's functions.php to select the add-ons automatically when the product is added to cart. Then add the function to the add-to-cart hook.

```
add_action('shopp_cart_add_item', 'my_function');
function my_function ( $Item ) {
// do stuff
}
```